# Make a TF Dataset from image filenames and corresponding string labels

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Up until a few months ago the data I was using to train my neural network (image classifier) was stored in a bucket in "keras format", where each image sat inside a folder that corresponded to the image class name:

```
top_dir/
    class1/
        image1.png
        image2.png

    class2/
        image3.png
        image4.png
```

In order to build the dataset I did this:

```
list_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files("top_dir/")

def decode_jpeg_and_label(filename: str):
    
    image_bytes = tf.io.read_file(filename)
    image = tf.image.decode_png(image_bytes, channels=3)
    image = tf.image.encode_jpeg(image, format='rgb', quality=100)
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3)
    label = tf.strings.split(tf.expand_dims(filename, axis=-1), sep='/')
    label = label.values[-2]
    return image, label

dataset = list_ds.map(decode_jpeg_and_label)
```

However, now the images are stored in a flat folder, and I get an API response which allows me to build the label data. The format of this is:

```
[["top_dir/image1.png", "class1"],
["top_dir/image2.png", "class1"],
["top_dir/image3.png", "class2"],
["top_dir/image4.png", "class2"]]
```

How can I take the input above and form it into a dataset equivalent to the one above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work, if your API response is `x`:

```
def load(file_path, label):
    img = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
    img = tf.image.decode_png(img, channels=3)
    img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32)
    img = tf.image.resize(img, size=(100, 100)) # optional
    label = tf.cast(tf.equal(label, 'class2'), tf.int32)
    return img, label

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x).map(lambda x: load(x[0], x[1]))

next(iter(ds))
```

```
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(100, 100, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
 array([[[0.40976474, 0.47250983, 0.56270593],
         [0.4039216 , 0.4666667 , 0.5568628 ],
         [0.41176474, 0.48235297, 0.57254905],
         ...,
         [0.5620584 , 0.5812747 , 0.6775489 ],
         [0.53252923, 0.5579019 , 0.6559411 ],
         [0.5176471 , 0.5568628 , 0.6509804 ]]], dtype=float32)>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=0>)
```

Comment: Thanks Nicolas, that's very useful, I can use this to do the conversion I need